# Как подключить css к Silex/Simfony

Tags: css, symfony2, silex

Composer

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~2.0",
        "twig/twig": "^1.26",
        "symfony/asset": "^3.1",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "^3.1"
    }
}
```

Не удается подлючить css/js.
Пробовал использовать asset :

```
 {% block stylesheets %}

        <link href="{{   asset('style.css','css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    {% endblock %}
```

Тем самым получаю полный путь:

/home/vagrant/Code/prach/web/../public/css/style.css

а в браузере ошибка :

404 Not Found - http://prach/home/vagrant/Code/prach/public/css/style.css"

в index.php  следующее :

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/../views'
));

;
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\AssetServiceProvider(), array(
    'assets.named_packages' => array(
        'css' => array(
            'base_path' => __DIR__ . '/../public/css'
        ),
        'js' => array(
            'base_path' => __DIR__ . '/../public/js'
        ),

        'images' => array(
            'base_path' => __DIR__ . '/../public/images'
        ),
    ),
));

$app['debug'] = true;


$app->get('/');

$app->get('/hello', function () use($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('hello.html.twig');
});

$app->run();
```

Правильно я понимаю, для css/js не нужно прописывать свой роут ?)

Comment: Относительно путей разобрался - добавил папку публик в корневую директорию и можно обойтись без asset() -

`` <link href="/public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 а как быть с asset ?

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить `asset` как `twig` функцию. В `silex2`:

```
$app['twig'] = $app->extend('twig', function ($twig, $app) {  
    $assetTwigFunc = new \Twig_SimpleFunction('asset', function ($localFile) use($app) {
        return $app['request_stack']->getCurrentRequest()->getBasePath() . '/' . $localFile;
    });

    $twig->addFunction($assetTwigFunc);

    return $twig;
});
```

И подключать статические файлы из `public` директории:

```
<title>{% block title '' %}</title>
<link href="{{ asset('/css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="{{ asset('/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

{% block scripts %}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```